# Why date when inserted into the column is translated to 2000-01-01?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I try to insert into a table value "28/09/2014 13:40:30.520153" all goes well. This code do that:

```
before_create :set_deadline

def set_deadline
  time_for_deadline = Sla.find(self.sla_id).time_for_deadline
  self.deadline = Time.now + time_for_deadline.hours
  return self.deadline
end
```

From logs:

---

### SQL (0.9ms) INSERT INTO "requests" /*some colums*/.... VALUES /*some values*/  RETURNING "id" [ /*some other values....*/, **["deadline", "2014-09-28 13:40:30.520153"]**,/*....some other..*/ ]]

But in the end in the table appears 01-01-2000. 
I think that this is due to the fact that the type of column - 'time', tried to change to datetime but there is an error:

### ERROR: column "deadline" is of type timestamp without time zone but expression is of type time without time zone at character 156 HINT: You will need to rewrite or cast the expression. : INSERT INTO "requests" ("comment", "created_at", "deadline", "division", "initiator", "responsible", "sla_id", "sla_number", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"

---

```
create_table "requests", force: true do |t|
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
...some colums here...
...
t.time "deadline"
```

end

What's wrong?

Comment: How did you change the type of the column?

Comment: rails g migration RemoveDeadlineFromRequests deadline:time and rails g migration AddDeadlineToRequests deadline:datetime and after that rake db:migrate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to restart Rails for it to pick up the change in your column type.

If you are running your application with `rails server`, it may be enough to break out of it with Control-C and start it again.

If that doesn't work, try running `spring stop` to force it to reload fully.

If you're using an external server such as Unicorn or Passenger, you'll need to restart it.

Comment: Thank you. It really helped. Even I do not understand how could I forget to restart the server!)